Make bootstrap modal footer button align side by side
I want the buttons to be side by side at right but the form seem to take too much of space.
the red box is the form container
<div class="modal-footer">
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
   <form method="post" action="{{ route('company.destroy', ['company' => $company]) }}">
       @csrf
        @method('delete')
        <input type="submit" value="Confirm Delete" class="btn btn-danger m-3" role="button" aria-pressed="true">
   </form>
</div>

I tried to use d-flex
<div class="modal-footer">
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-end">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary me-2 h-10" data-bs dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      <form method="post" action="{{ route('company.destroy', ['company' => $company]) }}">
         @csrf
         @method('delete')
         <input type="submit" value="Confirm Delete" class="btn btn-danger" role="button" aria-pressed="true">
      </form>
      </div>
</div>

and it came out like
this
I tried to control the form size
<form method="post" action="{{ route('company.destroy', ['company' => $company]) }}" class="w-25 h-10">
but the button position stays there, outside the form container and modal.
image

The buttons would align side by side, as modal footers already are flexbox containers with their content specified to align right, so your <div> with d-flex justify-content-end is unnecessary.
I’ve created an example jsfiddle where I took the demo modal from the Bootstrap 5 docs, added a form with a danger button inside it, and it renders like you want: https://jsfiddle.net/martinbean/Lu15xmeq/2/
